# What happens to a recycler view when the activity is destroyed?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-context

I am trying to understand what would happen to a recycler view which is populated using a RecyclerView.Adapter when the activity holding the recycler view is destroyed.

In my code, I pass the context of the activity which is holding the recycler view. When the orientation changes, the activity will be destroyed and recreated. This will make the context which was passed to the recycler view invalid. Does this lead to memory leak ? If yes, then what would be the best practice to avoid it ? If no, then how does android, especially the recycler view get the new context ?

This might be asked before and I would really appreciate if someone points me to the post.

Comment: you can use `this` as `Context` of an `Activity`.

Comment: Better is to use `context` from **view** inside your adapter by `view.getContext();`, in such a way, you won't be leaking context and also `NullPointerException`.

Comment: When the Activity gets destroyed, everything gets destroyed, including the RecyclerView. You create it again in the onCreate, so by default there is no leaks, unless there is a static variable or handler or thread holding on to them.

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not lead you to memory leak if you are passing the context non static. I means if you are passing the context in a static context then this is the problem leading to memory leak else you are good to go. nothing to worry about. If orientation gets changed all the references will be gone until you hold in bundle manually. And same goes to your recycler view and your passed context. Make sure you are not keeping static things like you mentioned context.